# How to parse data frames based on date

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a pandas data frame with the stock details of google. The index of the data frame is the date (from 2004-08-19 to 2018-05-05). I would like to split the data based on the year and store the closing value of the stock in a new data frame. The columns of the new data frame should be as follows
[2004, 2005, 2006, ... 2017, 2018]. The rows of the data frame should contain the closing value of the stock price for each day of the particular year.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of the input data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2004-08-19', periods=10, freq='6MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
            Price
2004-09-01      0
2005-03-01      1
2005-09-01      2
2006-03-01      3
2006-09-01      4
2007-03-01      5
2007-09-01      6
2008-03-01      7
2008-09-01      8
2009-03-01      9

df.index = [df.index.strftime('%m-%d'), df.index.year]
df = df['Price'].unstack()
print (df)
       2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009
03-01   NaN   1.0   3.0   5.0   7.0   9.0
09-01   0.0   2.0   4.0   6.0   8.0   NaN
```

Similar solution, but columns years are strings:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str).str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
df = df['Price'].unstack(0)
print (df)
       2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009
03-01   NaN   1.0   3.0   5.0   7.0   9.0
09-01   0.0   2.0   4.0   6.0   8.0   NaN
```